# Visual Studio Server Explorer connection test successful but linq to sql query fails

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, database-connection, server-explorer, visual-studio-2015

I have a werid problem. I am trying Linq to sql. I created my dataconnection to sql server via sql credentials. The test connection is fine and can see tables when I expand on server explorer but when I try and run my link to sql it errors saying failed to login.

I am just trying to get 1 value back matching on a where clause.

```
private static string FindUser(string picFileName)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            string userlogin = (from Directory in dataContext.Directories
                                where Directory.picFile == picFileName
                               select Directory.userLogin)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
            return userlogin;
        }
```

Comment: Probably means your connection string isn't right.

Comment: Yup, fix your connection string and it should work.

Comment: You should always include the exact text of the error message (after you google it and look for solutions on your own).

Comment: When in doubt, start a fresh project and make sure you follow all the steps: Add the dbml file, drag the tables you want to use from the database into the dbml, write your query, test it.

Comment: Great thanks. Recreated the connection worked.